# Swing: choice of layout and components for simple app

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a simple app that has:

- 2 TextFields with Labels: name and description
- Add button
- Panel that is filled with name/description labels and with radio buttons to select records and manipulate with them (edit / delete -> these buttons appear when radio button is selected).

I tried the following layouts composition:

- 2 Panels with BoxLayout (YAXIS) which contain text field and their labels
- Panel with GridBagLayout to have 2 panels with text fields and a button to add data.
- Panel with BoxLayout (YAXIS) to be filled with records after button press
- - Panel with GridBagLayout that contains radio button and 2 labels with results of name and description text fields.

Here is a screenshot of what I came to:

[image]

As you can see there's a problem - Labels have no word wrap. If I use JTextArea for word wraping, then white background appears (`setBackground(null)` doesn't help).

I think that GridBagLayout is not good choice here or even there are too many inner panels. In fact it seems this task is common enough. What are good practices for apps UI building like that one?

Comment: I am a big fan of the `FormLayout` of JGoodies, which makes writing such a panel a breeze. Others here are fan of the `MigLayout`

Comment: Try using multiple layouts.  Group each section of your form into separate panels and focus on their individual layout requirements.  You may even consider [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: You may also want to consider providing use with some idea of the layout you actually want as well ;)

Answer (score 3):

The Problem you got with your `JLabel` is easy to handle. Because JLabels accept `HTML Tags` you can use this mechanic to automaticly wrap your text:

```
label.SetText(String.format("<html><div WIDTH=%d>%s</div><html>", width, text));
```

For the general Layout I prefer the `GridbagLayout`. With the GridbagLayout you only need on Layout-Typ. GridBagLayout is flexible and easy to use for your case.

If the Layout will get more complex you will probably need to stack different Layouts, to get the best handling.

Comment: In fact I don't know the length of a string that will suit parent window width in order to place line breakers, if you mean this.